# How to display the object coming from API response using angular material table?

Tags: angular

I have an object coming from response which looks something [like](https://beta.randomapi.com/api/3141b5683af0edf576dabdb50ef1ff64?fmt=prettyraw&sole). It's a dynamic key value pair

```
{
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": "value2",
  "name3": "value3"
  ............
  ............
}
```

I want to generate a material table from this. I want to know how to get the response into my component file .

I'm getting the response in my service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });  
  url: string = '';  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.url = "https://beta.randomapi.com/api/3141b5683af0edf576dabdb50ef1ff64?fmt=prettyraw&sole"; 
   }
   public getData() {  
    return this.http.get(this.url )  
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => {  
        return res.json();  
      })); 

  }  


}
```

Comment: Where you are getting response as of now? in service? or in component?

Comment: I'm getting response in the service.

Comment: Subscribe to http response into the component, and render HTML accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First the datasource must be a array and the json you mentioned should be representing a row in table. Here is a sample [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-static) to use this. This will give you a direction to move forward.

Comment: My API response contains a dynamic key value pair. Something like the above, I want to know how to subscribe to the response.

Comment: If You check this link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-static

you will see that columns are generating dynamically from ELEMENT_DATA[0] - first row of the json. and table rows are getting generated dynamically. So if fields changes , table will be rendered accordingly.